# Substituting "remaining variables" during partial evaluation?

Tags: compilers, interpreters

In ["Partial Evaluation of Computation Process—An Approach to a Compiler-Compiler"](http://cs.au.dk/~hosc/local/HOSC-12-4-pp381-391.pdf) Yoshihiko Futamura wrote:

> "[Some] portions of a computation process [...] are not evaluated at
>   partial evaluation time, but the values are only substituted for the
>   **remaining variables.**"

on page 388 in the [paper](http://cs.au.dk/~hosc/local/HOSC-12-4-pp381-391.pdf)
(I considerably shortened the quote and I think that in order to answer my question you have to be familiar with the topic or read the paper anyway.)

Note that Futamura uses the term "remaining variables" to describe variables other than "partial evaluation variables", whose values are known - or can be calculated from other variables and constants - at partial evaluation time.

Now, the sentence would make perfect sense to me if the last occurence of "remaining variables" was replaced with "partial evaluation variables". After all, we can easily replace those with the values we know. But how should we be able to fill in the values for "remaining variables" when (of all things) they are the ones we don't know the values for (yet, i.e. at partial evaluation time)?

Could it be an error?
Do I read the sentence wrong?